# Open adjacent div on click

Tags: jquery, html, css

Morning,

I am looking for a solution that increases the size of an adjacent div on click. This is what I have but it doesn't seem to work:

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="button-1">Link</a>
<div id='ads-1'></div>
```

CSS

```
#ads-1{
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #6F0;
}
```

JS

```
$('#button-1').click(function(){
    $('#ads-1').animate({height:'500px'}, 500);
});
```

Comment: better to use `slideToggle` - http://jqapi.com/#p=slideToggle

Comment: It's working fine only. Just include jquery library. http://jsfiddle.net/j0bof3Lu/

Comment: I've included the Jquery library now, but still can't see it working, not even on JsFiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First include jQuery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

And wait for [document ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/):

```
$(function () {
    $('#button-1').click(function(){
        $('#ads-1').animate({height:'500px'}, 500);
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h73gqLet/).

Comment: Hmmm... Still not working for me... What on earth am i doing wrong!

Comment: press F12 and go into console to see if any errors encountered (In chrome)

Comment: Down-voted for advocating someone dump 70KB to achieve a simple goal leading them to learn not actual JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery isn't really necessary for something like this..  you could do it in a couple lines of CSS..

```
p { background-color:#6F0; }
span:focus ~ p { padding-bottom: 200px; }

<span tabindex="0">Link</span>
<p>Click the span and I'll grow taller</p>
```

http://cssdeck.com/labs/full/p2tdm8kp